# How can I download content from a webpage that requires login information

Tags: authentication, passwords, html

I am trying to create a small application that will download the content of a certain webpage. I am able to do that with certain web pages using WebRequest. However the web page I need to download from requires login information.

I am using C# and Visual Studio Express 2010

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [HttpWebRequest.Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.credentials.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can either simply use HttpWebRequest.Credentials as CesarGon mentioned or if it's HTTP Basic authorization, add an appropriate HTTP header (that would be environment independent):

```
Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

where dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ= is base 64 encoded username:password.